# Ввод данных в переменную и их вывод в модуле Discord.py

Tags: python, бот, discord

Я совсем недавно начал работать с модулем для Python 'Discord.py' и у меня появилась необходимость создания функции которая работает так: пользователь вводит текст, а бот этот текст переотправляет. Пожалуйста, помогите мне разобраться в том как это сделать.
Вот мой код:

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!");

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('!привет'):
        await message.channel.send(f' { message.author.mention }, Привет!')

    if message.content.startswith('!хелп'):
        await message.channel.send('Я бот, да ты и сам знаешь.\n**Мои команды:**\n```!привет - Вывод сообщения с приветом.``` ```!хелп - эта команда.```')

    if message.content.startswith('!print '): #После команды !print пользователь должен ввести текст который как-то нужно указать, возможно в переменной.
        await message.channel.send('') #Бот его должен вывести.

client.run('TOKEN')
````

Мой Python 3.7.0

Comment: @denisnumb, Больше Вам спасибо! Вы сильно мне помогли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть 2 типа ботов - `discord.Client()` и `commands.Bot()`

В коде вы объявляете обоих, но используете только первого - `client`:

**`bot`**`= discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")`

**`client`**`= discord.Client()`

Объект `bot` отличается тем, что умеет обрабатывать поступающие команды вместе с отдельными аргументами. Такие команды объявляются строкой `@bot.command()`, которая ставится перед асинхронной функцией команды. Объект `client` такую команду обработать не сможет. А вот `bot`, может помимо команды отлавливать также события, помеченные как `@bot.event`. К таким событиям относятся: `on_ready()` - вызывается когда бот загрузился и готов к работе, `on_message()` - вызывается при получении ботом любого сообщения, и др.

У вас в коде как раз таки присутствует обработка получения сообщения `on_message()`, в которой вы пытаетесь имитировать выполнение команд, путем сравнения поступающих слов. Это неправильно. Во всяком случае, это не то что вам нужно. Если вы хотите обрабатывать команды, с передачей в них различных аргументов, то использовать нужно именно объект `commands.Bot()`, который вы объявили в коде под именем `bot`. Далее к нему.

---

При определении объекта, в скобках вы указываете параметр `command_prefix`, равный значению `"!"`. Параметр *"префикс"* является обязательным и нужен для того, чтобы при его использовании бот определял, что в чате была использована именно команда. Сама команда выглядит следующим образом:

```
@bot.command() # указываем боту на то, что это его команда
async def command(ctx, *, text):
    await ctx.send(f'Получен текст: {text}')
```

Вызывается команда при написании в чат такой конструкции: *`[префикс][имя команды] [аргументы]`*

Для вызова этой команды нужно написать в чат *"!command текст, который нужно вернуть"*, на что бот ответит: *"Получен текст: текст, который нужно вернуть"*

Здесь `command` - название команды; Аргумент `ctx` - контекст, обязательный аргумент, грубо говоря, это текстовый канал, в котором была вызвана команда. Аргумент `text` будет содержать в себе весь текст после *"!command"*. Звездочка нужна для того, чтобы бот получил в качестве аргумента весь текст после пробела, а не только первое слово. То есть, если вам, например, нужно получить от пользователя 2 числовых значения, разделенные пробелом, обработка аргументов будет выглядеть так: `async def command(ctx, arg1: int, arg2: int)`

Из контекста `ctx` можно получить объект автора - `author = ctx.message.author` и еще много чего полезного. **Подробнее о работе с аргументами обязательно ознакомьтесь в [документации](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?)!**

---

Что касается вашего кода; Первым делом, предлагаю полностью убрать из него объект `discord.Client`, заменив его на `commands.Bot`. Чтобы не переписывать весь код, просто поменяем `bot` на `client` в строке `bot = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")`

Затем, объявим в коде полноценные команды и получим результат:

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.ext.commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.command()
async def привет(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.message.author.mention}, Привет!')

@client.command()
async def хелп(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Я бот, да ты и сам знаешь.\n**Мои команды:**\n```!привет - Вывод сообщения с приветом.``` ```!хелп - эта команда.```')

@client.command()
async def print(ctx, *, text):
    await ctx.send(f'{text}')   

client.run('TOKEN')
````

---

А в конструкции `on_message()` нужно обрабатывать именно те сообщения, которые не являются командой и при обработке которых не нужны аргументы. Например, через это событие можно отлавливать мат, после чего бот будет выдавать предупреждение участнику. Удачи :)